# How can I make a histogram with two consecutive bars in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data (replace this with your actual DataFrame)
data = {
    'CU': [1.5, 2.3, 1.8, 3.2, 2.5, 2.0, 3.8, 3.0],
    'ER': [0.2, 0.5, np.nan, 0.7, 0.8, 0.4, 0.9, 0.6],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data)

# Create a new column 'Valid_CU' where CU values are replaced with NaN if ER is NaN
df['Valid_CU'] = df['CU'].where(~df['ER'].isna())

hist_values, bin_edges,something= plt.hist([df['CU'], df['Valid_CU']], bins= 3,label=['Total Data', 'Valid Data'])
plt.xlabel('CU Values')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Histogram of CU Values with Valid Data Counts')
plt.legend()

print("hist",hist_values,"bind edges",bin_edges,"some",something)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

with this I get:

[image]

This is very nice! I have tried to do the same thing with Plotly without success. Plotly histograms give ugly representations and worst of all the values are all wrong.

How can I do the above in Plotly?

(Notice that in there, the bins is customizable. I want the same thing in Plotly).

### Post script

I would rather the following code not influence any answers. I write it as report. The most I could do was:

```
fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['CU'], y=[1] * len(df),name='Total Data'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Valid_CU'], y=[1] * len(df), name='Valid Data'))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Count of CU Values with Valid Data Counts',
    xaxis_title_text='CU Values',
    yaxis_title_text='Count',
    # barmode='overlay',  # overlay bars
    barmode='group'
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

But here the number of bins is not customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`go.Histogram`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Histogram.html)?

You can set the number of bins with `nbinsx`:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=df["CU"], nbinsx=3, name='Total Data'))
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=df["Valid_CU"], nbinsx=3, name='Valid Data'))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Count of CU Values with Valid Data Counts',
    xaxis_title_text='CU Values',
    yaxis_title_text='Count',
    # barmode='overlay',  # overlay bars
    barmode='group'
)

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the bins aren't the same as with matplotlib. You can however define the bins yourself:

```
xmin = df['CU'].min() * 0.99    
xmax = df['CU'].max() * 1.01
nbins = 3
xbins=go.histogram.XBins(size=(xmax-xmin)/nbins, start=xmin, end=xmax)

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=df["CU"], xbins=xbins, name='Total Data'))
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=df["Valid_CU"], xbins=xbins, name='Valid Data'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I have tried hours to get it right. Funnily checking my experiments I almost got your answer but forgot to try the combination `barmode='group' `and therefore failed. Thanks